# Some kind of Dirichlet principle generalization for prime number remainders

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

Suppose $p\in\mathbb{N}$ is prime, and $a_i=p^{m_i}r_i$ with $gcd(r_i,p)=1$. Consider the sum $S_k=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_k$, and suppose it is divided by $p^n$, and no "subsum" has the same property. That is, given any uncomplete set of indexes, $\{i_1,\ldots i_r\}$, an uncomplete sum $\sum\limits_{j\in \{i_1,\ldots i_r\}} a_j$ will not be $0\,\,\mod p^n$ (minimality condition). Then, I need to prove, one has $p^{m_1}+\ldots+p^{m_k}\leqslant p^n$.

I see that $n=1$ leads to the usual Dirichlet principle for remainders, since we necessariliy need to have $m_i=0$ and thus $p^{m_1}+\ldots+p^{m_k}=k$. Can it be generalized for $n\geq 2$?

Induction seems to be an appropriate instrument here. So $n=1$ is in fact the most begginer's problem with Dirichlet principle: if $p\,|\,r_1+\ldots+r_k$, then we get $k-1$ nonzero remainders, which cannot be unique, if $k>p$. In this case some sum $r_{t+1}+\ldots+r_{m}$ should be devided by $p$, and that contradicts minimality condition.

If by induction we jump from $n$ to $n+1$, one has $p^{n+1}u=r_1+\ldots+r_s+p(r_{s+1}p^{m_{s+1}-1}+\ldots+r_kp^{m_k-1})$ with $1\leq m_{s+1}\leq\ldots\leq m_k$. If $r_1+\ldots+r_s=p^gv$ (where $gcd(p,v)=1$), by induction hypothesis one has $p^g+p^{m_{s+1}}+\ldots+p^{m_k}\leq p^{n+1}$, after multiplication by $p$.

However, what we need is $s+p^{m_{s+1}}+\ldots+p^{m_k}\leq p^{n+1}$, and I don't see, if we could conclude $s\leq p^g$.

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$? IE To get $n = 2$, it must comprises of some $m_i = 1 $ and some $m_j = 0 $ (which must then sum up to $p$ or more).

Comment: Yes, trying, seems to be similarly difficult

Comment: Induction-esque is almost immediate. $\quad$ I've posted a solution but then deleted it, as MSE wants you to show your work instead of just begging for solutions.  If you show what you've tried for $n = 2$ and why you're stuck, I will undelete my solution.

Comment: Thanks, I posted my attempt, and where I got stuck

Comment: Right, so what you needed was a way to deal with the $s$. For $ s < p$, the conclusion is immediately. See how I dealt with $ s \geq p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Lemma: Out of any $p$ integers from $1$ to $p-1$, we can find a subset that sums to $p$.

  - I consider this to be the "usual Dirichlet principle for remainders" that OP referenced. If not, there are proofs of this on MSE.
- Now, suppose we have $a_i$ numbers with that satisfy the no "subsum" property but $ \sum p^{m_i } > p^n$.

  - For each $ i = 0 $ to $p-1$, let there be $b_i$ numbers which are of the form $p^i r$
  - Consider the number $b = \overline { b_{n-1} b_{n-2} \ldots b_1 b_0}_p$, where we allow $b_i \geq p$ if needed.  Since $ b > p^n$, this tells us that there is some $b_i > p$. Consider the smallest such index.
  - The lemma tells us that we can find some collection of these $p^i r$ numbers which has a sum that is a multiple of $p^{i+1}$.  Group these together as a new number.
  - Repeat the process working up from the smallest index with $b_i > p$.
  - We finally get to $b_{n-1} > p$, and are done from the lemma.
- To express the above as an induction proof on $n$ (which is slightly less motivating)

  - If $b_0 \geq p$, then keep on pulling out subsets which are a multiple of $p$ and treat them as a single term.
  - Once $b_0 < p$, then ignore those terms $p^0 r$, and divide the other terms by $p$. We're now in the $n-1$ case, hence done by induction.

Comment: Could you clarify how you pull subsets multiple of p? E.g., following induction, suppose $b_0>p$. Then there are some $r_i$ with $p^0$, which sum up to a multiple of $p$. Yes…

Comment: But why there will be more than $p$ summands for greater powers? Semmingly I miss the core of the procedure

Comment: 1/ Suppose $b_0 \geq p$, then by the Lemma we have some subset $I = \{ a_i \}$ with sum that is a multiple of $p$. Call this term $A_I = \sum a_i$, and take all of the other terms. Repeat. $\quad$ 2/ Think of what it means for $ b > p$, when read in base $p$. Since $ \overline{ (p-1)(p-1) \ldots (p-1) } _p = p^n - 1$, hence one of these $b_i$ must be $ \geq p$.

Comment: Got it, very cool, Calvin Lin. Thank you!